# Exibindo imagem no PDF dentro de um while

Tags: php, dompdf

Boa tarde, estou quebrando a cabeça, preciso exibir imagens do meu banco, em um PDF.
O nome do campo no banco, se chama `foto`, ele guarda o caminho das imagens que estão em um diretório.

SEM o **`DOMPDF`**, consigo exibir as imagens dessa forma em **PHP**:

```
echo"<td><img src='http://www.meusite.com/".$row_transacoes['foto']."' width='50'></td>";
```

Porém, com o **`DOMPDF`**, eu não consigo, talvez por que estou trocando alguns acentos, para "reconhecer", ai deixei assim:

```
$html .= '<td><img src="http://www.meusite.com/'.$row_transacoes['foto'].'" width="50"></td>';
```

E **não está funcionando**, aparece que a imagem não foi encontrada...

Vou estar deixando o código abaixo, agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda, estou há um tempão tentando...

```
<?php 
// CONEXÃO        
$host = "exemplo";
$user = "exemplo";
$key = "exemplo";
$bd = "exemplo";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $key, $bd);
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falha ao conectar ao banco: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}


    $html .= '<center><h3>Prontuário</h3></center>';
    $html .= '<table class="table">'; 
    $html .= '<thead>';
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<th>Nome</th>';
    $html .= '<th>Foto</th>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
    $html .= '</thead>';
    $html .= '<tbody>';

     // SELECT NOS CAMPOS A SEREM EXIBIDOS
    $result_transacoes = "SELECT nome, foto FROM clientes";

    $resultado_trasacoes = mysqli_query($con, $result_transacoes);

    while($row_transacoes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_trasacoes)){

        $html .= '<tr><td>'.$row_transacoes['nome'] . "</td>";
        $html .= '<td><img src="http://www.meusite.com/'.$row_transacoes['foto'].'" width="50"></td>';  

}
    $html .= '</tbody>';
    $html .= '</table';

  //referenciar o DomPDF com namespace
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;

  // include autoloader
    require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

  //Criando a Instancia
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

  // Carrega seu HTML
    $dompdf->load_html('
        <div class="header"> 
        <img src="timbrado.png" height="100%" width="100%">
        </div>

        '. $html .'

        '); 

  //Renderizar o html
    $dompdf->render();

  //Exibibir a página
    $dompdf->stream(
        "Prontuario.pdf", 
        array(
       "Attachment" => false //Para realizar o download somente alterar para true
   )
);
?>
```

> Eu consigo exibir imagem no **`DOMPDF`**, 
>   dessa forma:
>    `echo"<td><img src='http://www.meusite.com/uploads_foto/imagem.png' width='50'></td>";`
>
> Só **não estou conseguindo** com o `while` (`$row_transacoes['foto']`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o DOMPDF vem com imagens remotas desabilitadas, estranhamente aplicar somente:

```
$html .= '<td><img src="/'.$row_transacoes['foto'].'" width="50"></td>';
```

Deveria resolver, ou você não salvou corretamente ou se confundiu em algo no teste, mas de qualquer forma se precisar de imagens remotas deve-se usar o `Dompdf\Options`, assim:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
```

Segue um exemplo simplificado:

```
<?php

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$dompdf->loadHtml("
    <img src='/uploads_foto/Ademilson L.jpg' width='50%'><br>
    <img src='http://www.meusite.com/uploads_foto/Ademilson L.jpg' width='50%'>
");

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream('teste.pdf', array('Attachment' => false));
```

Comment: Isso... funcionou, muito obrigado pela atenção, desculpa qualquer coisa. Posso pedir para você editar e trocar o nome do meu site? se for possível...

Comment: @Samuel feito e comentários removidos ;)